Powershell script for deploying Qualys Agent on Azure VMs
I need to install Qualys Agent on Azure VMs but I am not able to use Powershell since I do not have the Qualys subscription license code as it is a multitenant license.
I need to follow the below steps for implementation:-
For Windows machines - I have the Qualys Agent exe file and the steps for installation are below
*********************************************************************                                                                                                                               Pre-requisites

Make sure you have root level/local admin privileges in order to execute installation commands.
Agent device must be able to reach the Qualys API URL https://qagpublic.qg1.apps.qualys.ae over HTTPS
port 443.
Deployment Steps Qualys Cloud Agents
Run Command Prompt or Terminal as admin/root.
Change directory to the location where Qualys Cloud Agent binaries are downloaded.
Use appropriate installation command as per the Operating System mentioned below.
Installation Commands as per Operating System
3.1. Windows Operating System agent installation command:
QualysCloudAgent.exe CustomerId={} ActivationId={} WebServiceUri=https://qagpublic.qg1.apps.qualys.ae/CloudAgent

For Linux Machines- I have the .rpm and .deb files and the installation steps are as below

Pre-requisites

Make sure you have root level/local admin privileges in order to execute installation commands.
Agent device must be able to reach the Qualys API URL https://qagpublic.qg1.apps.qualys.ae over HTTPS
port 443.
Deployment Steps Qualys Cloud Agents
Run Command Prompt or Terminal as admin/root.
Change directory to the location where Qualys Cloud Agent binaries are downloaded.
Use appropriate installation command as per the Operating System mentioned below.
Installation Commands as per Operating System
3.1. RPM Based Linux Operating System:
sudo rpm -ivh QualysCloudAgent.rpm
sudo /usr/local/qualys/cloud-agent/bin/qualys-cloud-agent.sh ActivationId=() CustomerId=()
ServerUri=https://qagpublic.qg1.apps.qualys.ae/CloudAgent/
3.2. Debian Based Linux Operating System:
sudo dpkg --install QualysCloudAgent.deb
sudo /usr/local/qualys/cloud-agent/bin/qualys-cloud-agent.sh ActivationId=(****) CustomerId=(*****)
ServerUri=https://qagpublic.qg1.apps.qualys.ae/CloudAgent

I need to create a  power shell script to perform the above mentioned steps and do a mass installation on all the existing VMs(Windows/Linux)
